# Changing IPs for all servers

Tags: networking, ip, ilo

We are in the process of changing all the IPs of all the servers in our department. I've never done it before so I just need some info on what to expect. We are "hoping" for smooth process. Below are the systems that we got that needs to change IPs:

2 - HP Onboard Managament
1 - SAN switch management
6 - iLOs
SANs
4 - Windows Server
Clustered virtual server

I'm just wondering if a sequence is needed to change the IPs on all these. Like which one needs to be change first and then next.(I hope I made sense)

Thanks guys in advance.

Comment: Make sure you adjust you DNS records in the process, it's not less important than typing correct subnet mask.

Answer (score 1):

You'll just have to think of it as a dependency graph, built up from a list of single dependence statements (edges). Here is a start (that may make a couple of assumptions from your list):

- The Servers should come up *after* the SAN since they (probably) depend on the SAN for their storage.
- If you don't have true console access, you probably want to do all the management and  lights-out interfaces first since they won't affect the current production operation of the servers.
- Cluster after all real hosts are changed and healthchecked since this depends on a happy, healthy batch of real hosts.

Of course also do some kind of dummy testing for routing purposes if this re-assignment is out of the old IP address' subnet.

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Here's what I got from you sugggestion: Management and iLos > SANs > Servers > Cluster. Is that correct? Thanks!

Comment: The order you have listed is how I would do it (given the level of detail that we are discussing at). Sorry for the late reply.